# Can we use the default service account of a VM in gcp to call api's?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I am trying to list the Storage Buckets within an Organization using REST API.
I am running this code in a VM, currently I created a user managed Service Account and passing its key as a credential in the code.

Instead of passing the Service Account key as a credential:

1. Can i use the service account of the VM to list the Storage Buckets in an Organization?
2. How can we configure  the code to use the VM service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your VM you can [define the service account that you want to use](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#user-managed). By doing this, you configure the metadata server that run behind your VM.

The Client Libraries knows how to leverage the metadata server information. For that, you have nothing special to do, simply get the default configuration (usually like that `storage.Client()`).

Then, you have to grant that service account at the Organization level (on the console select the org id, and go to IAM to grant your service account).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes we can use the service account.
2. Define VM service account as the authentication in code. You can try this code snippet based from the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code). Make sure that the correct dependencies are installed and you have the copy of the Service Account inside the local of the VM Instance.

```
def explicit():
    from google.cloud import storage

    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'service_account.json')

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you run you code inside Google Cloud under some service account. And you would like to use some Google Cloud services APIs. In your example - storage API.

In that case you might not need any keys or json files. You might prefer to grant your service account relevant IAM roles explicitly, maybe during deployment time. And in you code it would not be necessary to create a storage client using some key file.